# How do i access my tabpage name form a usercontrol? C#

Tags: c#, tabs

this is my first time using stackoverflow so im sorry for anything i do wrong.

Im have having a issue making a tabbed web browser in Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express Edition, the problem is that i want the tab page to be named the webpage name but im using a instance of a usercontrol for each tab and beacause the tabcontrol is not static i cant change the name from the usercontrol class. What do i do to fix this?

Any tips will help.
Thanks!

Comment: This makes little sense.  What is supposed to happen when you visit 123.html?  What is the advantage anyway?  Just use another property of the tab page.  like Tag.  Raise an event when the visited page changes.

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear. From what I gather you are making a web browser application in C# (WinForms) and are attempting to change the parent tab control's text from objects (usercontrols) within the tab. Adding more information will yield more answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Control.Parent` property to access the containing Control. Here we hook up the TabPage so that changing the UserControl's Text property automatically updates the parent TabPage. You can perform this hookup when you create the new TabPage and UserControl.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form form = new Form
        {
            Controls =
            {
                new TabControl
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Name = "TabControl1",
                    TabPages =
                    {
                        new TabPage { Name = "Page1", Text = "Page 1", Controls = { new UserControl { } } },
                        new TabPage { Name = "Page2", Text = "Page 2", Controls = { new UserControl { } } },
                    },
                },
            },
        };

        // Hookup the TabPage so that when it's UserControl's Text property changes, its own Text property is changed to match
        // Now you can simply alter the UserControl's Text property to cause the TabPage to change
        foreach (TabPage page in ((TabControl)form.Controls["TabControl1"]).TabPages)
            page.Controls[0].TextChanged += (s, e) => { Control c = (Control)s; c.Parent.Text = c.Text; };

        // Demonstrate that when we change the UserControl's Text property, the TabPage changes too
        foreach (TabPage page in ((TabControl)form.Controls["TabControl1"]).TabPages)
            page.Controls[0].Text = "stackoverflow.com";

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```